# Get a warning when I try to perform ANOVA with 4 variables

Tags: r, warnings, anova

So I have data with 4 variables. Each variable has difference numbers of variants such as 2, 3, 4, and 4. Through the combination of each variables I have 96 total numbers of result. Then, I want to perform ANOVA using R in rstudio. My code to perform ANOVA is below.

```
#perform anova
jarak <- lm(R ~ p*V*h*s, data = pakan)
anova(jarak)
Anova(jarak, type = "III")
summary(jarak)
vif(jarak)
```

But, after I run the `anova(jarak)` I got a warning result like below.

```
> anova(jarak)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: R
          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
p          1   65104   65104     NaN    NaN
V          2 2066458 1033229     NaN    NaN
h          3   22812    7604     NaN    NaN
s          3   31146   10382     NaN    NaN
p:V        2  140208   70104     NaN    NaN
p:h        3   12812    4271     NaN    NaN
V:h        6   61875   10313     NaN    NaN
p:s        3   29479    9826     NaN    NaN
V:s        6   53542    8924     NaN    NaN
h:s        9   54271    6030     NaN    NaN
p:V:h      6  108125   18021     NaN    NaN
p:V:s      6   21458    3576     NaN    NaN
p:h:s      9   84271    9363     NaN    NaN
V:h:s     18  114792    6377     NaN    NaN
p:V:h:s   18  153542    8530     NaN    NaN
Residuals  0       0     NaN               
Warning message:
In anova.lm(jarak) :
  ANOVA F-tests on an essentially perfect fit are unreliable
```

Is there any problem with my code? I have followed all instructions that I found at YT to perform ANOVA in rstudio. Or is it because of I can't run 4-way ANOVA in rstudio? Please guide me. It's my first time using rstudio for my work. Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: How many observations do you have in your data? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: The clue is in your residual df. It’s zero. Your model is over saturated. Also, many statisticians have a problem with Type III SS in interaction models.  They adjust interactions for main effects and main effects for interactions, which makes interpretation difficult.